# Transparent reverse proxy to SSL host

Tags: nginx, squid

I'll just explain my case.

I have a HTTPS website say `https://**site.com` which is located on some servers. Those server IPs are blocked for the clients. So I need to make this site available for clients browsers transparently.

So client browser goes to `https://unblocked.**site.com` and gets the requests content as it where original `https://**site.com`

I can crete those forwarding server on IP which is not blocked and can access orinal site. How should I configure my server (that will be mapped to unblocked.**site.com in DNS) to accomplish that?

Can I use nginx for such task? Or should I try squid?

I tried to configure nginx using config like that:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name unblocked.**site.com;
    location / {
        set $upstream **site.com;
        proxy_pass https://$upstream;
    }
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

why I try to do `curl https://unblocked.**site.com` I get the error:

```
curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_INVALID_TOKEN (0x80090308) - The token supplied to the function is invalid
```

My experices with squid is quite limited, I used to use it as transparent proxy, but not for such task.

So again: And I am asking is solution possible without installing certs on reverse proxy? If it can't be done with nginx maybe with some other solution for example squid? Or such transparent scheme is not possible in principle?

Comment: ServerFault is more about implementing and enforcing policies rather than circumvention ... - But implementing a reverse proxy innginx should work (but only for sites that don’t block acces from alternative URL’s )

Comment: So why does my nginx config doesn't work? I aded a client's error message in OP.

Comment: Client error messages are not nearly as useful to a server admin as the errors the server logs

Comment: For nginx to be an httpS (secure aka SSL/TLS) server, you must at minimum tell it to use `ssl` protocol and give it a suitable certificate (trusted by your clients) and matching privatekey; see http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html to start.

Comment: Its not really transparent if you terminate the TLS. Can you get a DNS for 'untrusted' as a subdomain of the domain owner you are bypassing their access control of?

Comment: @danblack didn't get your question about DNS.

Comment: sorry mean 'unblocked', not 'untrusted'. How are you going to get a DNS entry (and SSL certificate) for the `unblocked.**site.com` domain off the owners of `**site.com`, when they are the ones blocking your clients? Maybe this is just an example and you're really doing `unblocked.anotherdomain.com`. Doesn't matter a lot to the final technical solution. FWIW the nginx ssl server needs to be populated with ssl certificates and key settings matching the domain where its hosted.

Comment: well my server which is blocked from ceratin clients can have `unblocked.**site.com` cert. And I am asking is solution possible without installing certs on reverse proxy? If it can't be done with nginx maybe with some other solution for example squid? Or such transparent scheme is not possible in principle?